# What does かかっといで mean?

Tags: particle-で, contractions, imperatives

「もう一度かかっといで」。

At the beginning, I thought it was 掛かって + ぐ ending verb turned into its imperative mood; then I've found かかってこい, it would make sense. If so, why does で appear? Is と the contraction for てこ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

かっかといで is just a contraction of かかっておいで "Come at me!". (The contraction of て＋お > と is the same one that occurs in -ておく > -とく.)

As you may know, おいで is a fossilised form of the honorific of くる (おいでになる), used exclusively as an imperative. So essentially, this *is* just equivalent to かかってこい.